# Apple ID. Problem with iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I took a video on my iPhone 3GS, and I don't want anyone seeing it because it's personal to me. Now I'm worried because of iCloud. I sold my friend my 2-3rd gen iPod about a year ago, and in worried he might be able to see this video through iCloud.

When I sold it to him, I gave him my Apple ID to share. I have changed it several times but I'm worried he might still be able see this video even though I gave changed pass.

Comment: But what if your friend downloaded all the videos from the account back when they had the password that worked? In other words it was moved from the cloud to their actual hard drive in their computer. In that instance they would have it and likely have seen it. They might not be saying anything because it's embarrassing or such. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed your password since you gave your friend your Apple ID, then he/she will be unable to access iCloud, or any other service that uses your ID. (Unless they are a great hacker, but that is unlikely)

Unless you give them the new password, they will have lost access to your apple account completely.

From this, I am fairly sure your video is safe.